# How to make this python script run faster?

Tags: python

Im trying to parse mediawiki dump files, by opening each URL in the abstract dump file and parsing it using BS4.
I have about 600k URLs which according to my estimation will take 200 Hour.

```
sentenceTokens = []


with open('arwiki-latest-abstract.txt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as textFile:  # open text file
    for line in textFile:
        if '<url>' in line:
            line = re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', line)  # remove <> and anything within
            line = re.sub('\n', '', line)
            print(line)
            requestURL = urllib.request.Request(line, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # read webpage
            try:
                scrapeURL = urllib.request.urlopen(requestURL)  # scrape webpage
            except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
                continue
            article = scrapeURL.read()
            parsedArticle = bs.BeautifulSoup(article, 'lxml')  # parse webpage
            paragraphs = parsedArticle.find_all('p')  # split article to paragraphs
            textFromURL = ""
            for paragraph in paragraphs:
                textFromURL += paragraph.text  # concat paragraphs
            textFromURL = re.sub('[\[].*?[\]]', ' ', textFromURL)  # remove [] and anything within
            textFromURL = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', textFromURL)  # fix spaces
            textFromURL = araby.strip_tashkeel(textFromURL)
            sentenceTokens += nltk.sent_tokenize(textFromURL)
worddict, wordcount = vocab.build_dictionary(sentenceTokens)
vocab.save_dictionary(worddict, wordcount, 'D:\\Unsupervisedsummarization')
with open('listtext.txt', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as strlist:
    pickle.dump(sentenceTokens, strlist)
```

If anyone could parallelize this code please or offer some tips on how to make it run faster.
Thanks!

Comment: simply parallelize the for loop -- it is I/O bound

Comment: package your crawling into one single function, and map your list of urls to that function with a `ThreadPool`

Comment: You might also find downloads of the data that you are scraping. If you can get a download the processing will be much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to parallelize url requests and bs4 parsing, as most slow processes, like in the example:

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from aiohttp import ClientSession, client_exceptions
from asyncio import Semaphore, ensure_future, gather, run
from json import dumps, loads

limit = 10
http_ok = [200]


async def scrape(url_list):

    tasks = list()

    sem = Semaphore(limit)

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for url in url_list:
            task = ensure_future(scrape_bounded(url, sem, session))
            tasks.append(task)

        result = await gather(*tasks)

    return result


async def scrape_bounded(url, sem, session):
    async with sem:
        return await scrape_one(url, session)


async def scrape_one(url, session):

    try:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            content = await response.read()
    except client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError:
        print('Scraping %s failed due to the connection problem', url)
        return False

    if response.status not in http_ok:
        print('Scraping%s failed due to the return code %s', url, response.status)
        return False

    content = loads(content.decode('UTF-8'))

    return content


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['http://demin.co/echo1/', 'http://demin.co/echo2/']
    res = run(scrape(urls))

    print(dumps(res, indent=4))
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/",
        "ip": "188.103.31.169",
        "headers": {
            "X-Forwarded-Host": "demin.co",
            "X-Forwarded-Port": "80",
            "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http",
            "X-Forwarded-Agent": "Python/3.7 aiohttp/3.5.4",
            "X-Forwarded-Request": "GET /echo1/ HTTP/1.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/",
        "ip": "188.103.31.169",
        "headers": {
            "X-Forwarded-Host": "demin.co",
            "X-Forwarded-Port": "80",
            "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http",
            "X-Forwarded-Agent": "Python/3.7 aiohttp/3.5.4",
            "X-Forwarded-Request": "GET /echo2/ HTTP/1.1"
        }
    }
]
```

You can see source code [here](https://github.com/caa06d9c/Examples/blob/master/Python/basic/asyncio/requests_web_semaphore/run.py).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i only have one question though.. 
content = await response.read()
Whats the type of content and how can i connect it with BS4,
will this work?
bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

Comment: I've updated answer, u can try it. For bs4 u need to change content = loads to soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="lxml") and so on, like item = soup.find('h2', attrs={'class': 'title'}).text, return item . Scrape return the list of results from scrape_one. Exampe show the list of dicts (server returns json)

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly!
I had to remove content = loads(content.decode('UTF-8')) it caused an error for some reason. instead, i just loaded contents into BS4. Thanks!

Comment: After a bit of testing, i end up with 'RuntimeError: can't start new thread'
then 'During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:'
'MemoryError' after that, my console gets flooded with 'Task was destroyed but it is pending!'

I suspect the threads are not being closed but im not sure, what are your thoughts about this?

Comment: I did vote it but i have less than 15 reputation which means it will count but it will not show on display.

Comment: I used asyncio with 100 flows to grep 10000 URLs with hard scraping (xml and bs4), and everything was ok. as everything else related to asynchronous  and multiprocessing calculations you should verify that amount of resources is enough. that is why tools like nginx so popular, they do it very carefully. try to reduce the amount of parallel requests. start from 1 and increase step-by-step. also you need to check that you don't have a loop inside functions, that you set up timeouts for scraping (because default timeout is too big, it can cause a huge amount of pending requests). and use debug)

Comment: I partitioned the 690k URLsinto 690 files, each file contatining 1k URLs, and had the run command run each file at a time, this solved my problem with creating new threads.
However, several links result in 'Scraping failed due to the return code ' due to their response.status not being in http_ok. could you explain what this means please? is the link dead or is it a connection problem?

Comment: it means that server returned something else, not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success.